# How to handle "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

When `k!=0` solve_ivp gives me this error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

I think the problem is when `k!=0` `fkm` becomes an array and I'm trying to put in `sol` array

But I couldn't find a way to solve the problem. Any ideas?

Edit: I tried `vectorized=True` but didn't work.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp, solve_ivp
from numpy import sin, cos, pi
from scipy.special import binom

E = 200e9
nu = 0.3
Q = -10e3

a = 1
b = 2
t0 = 0.01

D0 = E*t0**3/(12*(1-nu**2))
e = 0

def t(y): return t0*(1+e*y)

def D(y): return D0*(1+e*y)**3

def D(i,y): return D0*binom(3,i)*y**i

def Dy(i,y): return D0*binom(3,i)*(i)*y**(i-1)

def Dyy(i,y): return D0*binom(3,i)*(i)*(i-1)*y**i-2

N = 3
N_nodes = 10

x = np.linspace(0, a, N_nodes)   
y = np.linspace(0, b, N_nodes)

Y_arr = np.zeros((N_nodes, 5, N_nodes))
def Y(k,m):
    if (k==0):
        fkm = 4*Q/(m*pi*D0)
    else:
        fkm = np.zeros((N_nodes))
        for i in range(1,k+1):
            Y, Yy, Yyy, Yyyy, Yyyyy = Y_arr[k-i]
            A = D(i,y)*Yyyyy + 2*Dy(i,y)*Yyyy-2*(m*pi/a)**2*Dy(i,y)*Yy
            B = (Dyy(i,y) - 2*D(i,y)*(m*pi/a)**2)*Yyy
            C = (D(i,y)*(m*pi/a)**4-nu*(m*pi/a)**2*Dyy(i,y))*Y
            fkm += -1/D0*(A+B+C)
    def dU_dy(y,U):
        sol = np.zeros((4,N_nodes))
        sol = [U[1],U[2],U[3],fkm + 2*(m*pi/a)**2*U[2]-(m*pi/a)**4*U[0]]
        return sol
    def BCs(y0, yb):
        Y0, Y0y, Y0yy, Y0yyy = y0
        Yb, Yby, Ybyy, Ybyyy = yb
        return [Y0, Y0yy, Yb, Ybyy]

    Y_guess = solve_ivp(dU_dy,(0,b),[0,1,0,1],t_eval=y,vectorized=False).y
    Y, Yy, Yyy, Yyyy = solve_bvp(dU_dy, BCs, y, Y_guess, max_nodes=N_nodes).y
    Yyyyy = fkm + 2*(m*pi/a)**2*Yyy-(m*pi/a)**4*Y

    Y_arr[k] = np.array([Y, Yy, Yyy,Yyyy, Yyyyy])

    return Y

w = np.zeros((N_nodes, N_nodes))
for k in range(N):
    wk = np.zeros((N_nodes,N_nodes))
    for m in range(1,N+1):
        wk += np.outer(Y(k,m),sin(m*pi*x/a))
    w += wk*(e**k)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-01b7605c068b> in <module>()
     38     wk = np.zeros((N_nodes,N_nodes))
     39     for m in range(1,N+1):
---> 40         wk += np.outer(Y(k,m),sin(m*pi*x/a))
     41     w += wk*(e**k)

<ipython-input-58-01b7605c068b> in Y(k, m)
     26         return [Y0, Y0yy, Yb, Ybyy]
     27 
---> 28     Y_guess = solve_ivp(dU_dy,(0,b),[0,1,0,1],t_eval=y,vectorized=True).y
     29     Y, Yy, Yyy, Yyyy = solve_bvp(dU_dy, BCs, y, Y_guess, max_nodes=N_nodes).y
     30     Yyyyy = fkm + 2*(m*pi/a)**2*Yyy-(m*pi/a)**4*Y

d:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\ivp.py in solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method, t_eval, dense_output, events, vectorized, args, **options)
    541         method = METHODS[method]
    542 
--> 543     solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
    544 
    545     if t_eval is None:

d:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\rk.py in __init__(self, fun, t0, y0, t_bound, max_step, rtol, atol, vectorized, first_step, **extraneous)
     93         self.max_step = validate_max_step(max_step)
     94         self.rtol, self.atol = validate_tol(rtol, atol, self.n)
---> 95         self.f = self.fun(self.t, self.y)
     96         if first_step is None:
     97             self.h_abs = select_initial_step(

d:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\base.py in fun(t, y)
    137         def fun(t, y):
    138             self.nfev += 1
--> 139             return self.fun_single(t, y)
    140 
    141         self.fun = fun

d:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\base.py in fun_single(t, y)
    124         if vectorized:
    125             def fun_single(t, y):
--> 126                 return self._fun(t, y[:, None]).ravel()
    127             fun_vectorized = self._fun
    128         else:

d:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\base.py in fun_wrapped(t, y)
     19 
     20     def fun_wrapped(t, y):
---> 21         return np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)
     22 
     23     return fun_wrapped, y0

d:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: The problem is in the return value of `dU_dy`.  As per docs it should be a numeric array with shape (n,) or (n,k).  You return a list, forcing `solve_ivp` to do the conversion for you, and it fails (not necessarily at the first iteration).

Comment: @hpaulj How do i return an array with shape (n,k) without failing?

Comment: Figure out why it is failing, and solve that issue!

Comment: @hpaulj I'm trying to solve for two days that's why I'm here. I couldn't find how to return (n,k) array in the docs. I've  tried `vectorized=True`

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that both of your cases `k==0` and `k!=0` both return that same data type and shape, this will help the solver. I do not know the specifics of your problem, but if `fkm` needs to be an array in one case then it should be an array in the other case and you can work out the specifics of what that means.

I have tried to edit your `Y` function, but without understanding the problem specifics I'm not sure I can help more:

```
def Y(k,m):
    if (k==0):
        # for k==0 make fkm a list of N_nodes with same value
        fkm = [4*Q/(m*pi*D0)]*N_nodes
    else:
        fkm = np.zeros((N_nodes))
        for i in range(1,k+1):
            Y, Yy, Yyy, Yyyy, Yyyyy = Y_arr[k-i]
            A = D(i,y)*Yyyyy + 2*Dy(i,y)*Yyyy-2*(m*pi/a)**2*Dy(i,y)*Yy
            B = (Dyy(i,y) - 2*D(i,y)*(m*pi/a)**2)*Yyy
            C = (D(i,y)*(m*pi/a)**4-nu*(m*pi/a)**2*Dyy(i,y))*Y
            fkm += -1/D0*(A+B+C)

    def dU_dy(y,U):
        sol = np.zeros((4,N_nodes))
        # then add all N_node values of fkm to solver (so all 10 are there in this case)
        sol = [U[1],U[2],U[3]] + (fkm + 2*(m*pi/a)**2*U[2]-(m*pi/a)**4*U[0]).tolist()
        return sol
    def BCs(y0, yb):
        Y0, Y0y, Y0yy, Y0yyy = y0
        Yb, Yby, Ybyy, Ybyyy = yb
        return [Y0, Y0yy, Yb, Ybyy]

# then N_node guesses are need for solver
Y_guess = solve_ivp(dU_dy,(0,b),[0,1,0] +[1]*N_nodes,t_eval=y,vectorized=False).y
Y, Yy, Yyy, Yyyy = solve_bvp(dU_dy, BCs, y, Y_guess, max_nodes=N_nodes).y
```

For both `k==0` and `k==1` the `solve_ivp` line passes without hitch, however `solve_bvp` now needs to be looked at.

Answer (score 0):

When I put a:

```
U = np.array([[0],[1],[0],[1]])
print(k, dU_dy(0, U))
print(np.array(dU_dy(0, U), float))
```

before the `solve_ivp` call, I get:

```
1323:~/mypy$ python3 stack61661864.py 
0 [array([1]), array([0]), array([1]), array([-0.69518879])]
[[ 1.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.        ]
 [-0.69518879]]
0 [array([1]), array([0]), array([1]), array([-0.3475944])]
[[ 1.       ]
 [ 0.       ]
 [ 1.       ]
 [-0.3475944]]
0 [array([1]), array([0]), array([1]), array([-0.2317296])]
[[ 1.       ]
 [ 0.       ]
 [ 1.       ]
 [-0.2317296]]
1 [array([1]), array([0]), array([1]), array([-0.0819576 ,  0.0122602 ,  0.00429568,  0.00517298,  0.00733516,
        0.00895909,  0.00857527,  0.00368501,  0.060713  ,  1.47233495])]
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack61661864.py", line 72, in <module>
    wk += np.outer(Y(k,m),sin(m*pi*x/a))
  File "stack61661864.py", line 57, in Y
    print(np.array(dU_dy(0, U), float))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

It runs fine for `k=0`, `sol` is a list of 4 (1,) shape arrays, which makes (4,1) array.

But for `k=1`, the 4th term is a (10,) shape array.  That `sol` cannot be turned into an array.

For `k=0`, `fkm = 4*Q/(m*pi*D0)`.  This must be a scalar. But for other `k`, it is `fkm = np.zeros((N_nodes))`

As I commented, you need to make sure the function to `ivp/bvp` returns an array with the correct shape.  I tested `sol` with a variety of `print` statements.  Calling `dU_dy` by itself, as I demo here, is a good way of checking it (provided the inputs match what the solver sends).

Check shapes, and check them again!